# what file do I have to edit to make vim start with some context automatically? like Visual Studio

Tags: vim

I want not to type

```
#include
using namespace std
int main()
...
```

everytime, so what I want is like when I type like this in cmd
gvim -option hello.cpp

gvim starts with this code automatically

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
...
```

Can I do this?

Comment: I have updated the answer for creating your own mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noah Frederick has a very interesting article entitled: "[File Templates with UltiSnips and Projectionist](https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist)" and it combines file templates with ultisnips

Basically, if the new file is empty it inserts a snippet `_skel` automatically. The advantage of this method is that a template is dynamic instead of a static template.

OBS: I am not sharing the code here to give Noah the credit, I believe it is worth reading the whole article.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do even better

short answer: take a look at this plugin https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips

---

see `:h vimrc`

long answer: vim is very customizable editor you have option to create your own mapping see `:help map-commands`

and with help of `read` see `:help read`  you can read content of any file or external command

now with combining these two things lets say you create a simple file in `~/.vim/snips` folder called `cppHello.snip` and you place content inside it

now you create a mapping let's say `nnoremap <leader>hw :read ~/.vim/snips/cppHello.snip<cr>` ( see `:h <Leader>`) now everytime you type `<leader>hw` vim will place the content of above file in your current buffer bellow your cursor position

Comment: But instead of a mapping, why not create an automatic solution?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble the point is you don't  want vim to add some content everytime you open a file with it 

and if you do this by adding a command line flag you still have to do the typing and will only work when vim is getting started 

by creating a mapping you can insert the content whenever you want wherever you want

Comment: you can do that as well whatever works for the user thats why vim is awesome

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for additional plugins as vim's `autocmd` can be used for use-cases like this. See `:h autocmd` for more info.

Here's how you do it. Add the following lines to your `vimrc` file, if you don't have a vimrc file already, lookup how to add one using `:h vimrc`

```
augroup CppContext
  autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp execute 'silent! 1s/.*/#include\rusing namespace std\rint main()'
augroup end
```

Reopen vim using `vim your_file_name.cpp` and you should have the lines mentioned added automatically.

---

#### Explanation

- using `BufNewFile` event, you can execute steps/commands when *starting to edit a non-existent file*
- With `*.cpp` we're using file globbing and matching only `.cpp` files
- And everything to the right of the `*.cpp` is the command, which basically enters the text you wanted.